# Python multithreading.pool running slower than sequential

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am trying to make one of my functions run `asynchronous`. In the code this function runs approximately 600-700 times. So I am trying to make it asynchronous so overall code will be faster.
I am using `threadpool` for it to run faster. But as I searched for solutions I saw something called `GIL`(Global Interpreter Lock). If I understood correctly because python is not a thread safe language, GIL doesn't let python use more than one thread at a time.

Here is the piece of code I am trying to run asynchronous. Function was too long so I pasted here the time consuming part.

```
    for row in range(0, image_row-1 ,1):
        if row in ignore_row:
            continue
        for column in range(0, image_col-1 ,1):

            if image_binary[row][column] > 0:

                #For the first triangle of a square
                vertice1 = vertices[row][column]
                vertice2 = vertices[row][column+1]
                vertice3 = vertices[row+1][column+1]
                face1 = np.array([vertice1, vertice2, vertice3])
                #For the second triangle if a square
                vertice1 = vertices[row][column]
                vertice2 = vertices[row+1][column]
                vertice3 = vertices[row+1][column+1]
                face2 = np.array([vertice1,vertice2,vertice3])
                faces.extend(face1)
                faces.extend(face2)
```

At first I thought if one of the variables was global maybe the threads are waiting in the queue to access it. But non of the variables are global they all created in the function.
In the sequential code for 1 run all program takes about 0.2 seconds but in the parallel program in this snippet it takes about 4-9 seconds.

Here is the multiprocess code:

```
pool = ThreadPool(config.THREAD_COUNT)   
pool.map(process_image, png_names)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

`png_names` holds the name of the png's in a folder.
And for `config.THREAD_COUNT` i tried 2-17 threads. They all read the png files and start to process it but when they come to the part that i shared above they wait and execute that part in about 4-9 seconds.

I am using `cv2` and `numpy` libraries for reading and editing the images.
I am using `Python 3.10`

Comment: If this is a compute heavy operation I don't see why threading would make it any faster. The process of reading 700 images and evaluating them takes 0.2 seconds in the consecutive approach?

Comment: Not excatly. I am trying to use threads so i can read more than one image at the same time. 0.2 is one individual layers reading time. Sometimes it takes longer sometimes it is shorter. Right now for 300 layers it takes about 200 seconds. And I am trying to make it faster. As the snippet I shared takes the most time in the code if I can make it threaded it would save so much time for me.

Comment: I would suggest you try out multiprocessing then instead of threading. I'm not entirely sure what it is you're trying to do as your snippet is not something I can try for myself.